# How to have a figure legend and a subplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, subplot

I would like to plot some data in subplots and I would like to have a legend for the overall figure but also a legend for one of the subplots, where the labels of the subplot should not appear in the figure label.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

a = np.random.rand(5)
b = np.random.rand(5)
a1 = np.append(a, 0.5)
b1 = np.append(b, 0.5)

ax[0].plot(a, color='red', label='one')
ax[0].plot(b, color='blue', label='two')

ax[1].plot(a1, color='red', label='one appended')
ax[1].plot(b1, color='blue', label='two appended')
ax[1].legend()

fig.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get rid of the 'one appended' and 'two appended' labels in the figure legend?

Comment: Either just plot the legend for the ax[0] or the other way is just to create a custom legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

a = np.random.rand(5)
b = np.random.rand(5)
a1 = np.append(a, 0.5)
b1 = np.append(b, 0.5)

ax[0].plot(a, color='red')
ax[0].plot(b, color='blue', label='two')
ax[0].legend(['one','two'])

ax[1].plot(a1, color='red')
ax[1].plot(b1, color='blue')
ax[1].legend(['one appended', 'two appended'])

fig.legend(["one whole", "two whole"])

plt.show()
```

I don't know if this helps you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).